# Rsyslog tagging of log from external application

Tags: rsyslog

I have an application which send its log to rsyslog port. The current format is like

DATE HOSTNAME {Log}

I'm looking for a option to tag them, so that log structure looks

DATE HOSTNAME SYSLOG_TAG.

Tagging at application level is not happening, or is messing up. Any option to get it tagged at rsyslog level. I can find examples to tag them when reading from a file, but not from port.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I did an on the fly tagging using omfwd and the config look like

```
If $msg contains 'production-sensu' then
set $.appname = "MYTAGNAME";
$template MYTEMPLATE, "%TIMESTAMP% %HOSTNAME% %$.appname%  %rawmsg% \n"
action(type="omfwd"
Target="logserver"
Port="port"
Protocol="tcp"
Template="MYTEMPLATE"
)
& ~
```

But now the head ache is that I can't drop the`enter code here` default message. The that comes before tagging also gets forwarded.